Cannot build my project on adding "aws-sdk-apigatewaymanagement" to it. How do I fix this issue?
I am having an issue while building the project using cargo build after adding aws-sdk-apigatewaymanagement to my project. I identified this issue by checking out to a previous commit, which built and ran properly, where I hadn't added the aws-sdk-apigatewaymanagement package. On adding the package to this branch and running it again, this error popped up.
Here is the error
   Compiling aws-smithy-runtime v1.3.1
error[E0446]: private type `UploadThroughputCheckFuture` in public interface
   --> /Users/amanr/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/aws-smithy-runtime-1.3.1/src/client/http/body/minimum_throughput.rs:333:1
    |
213 | / pin_project_lite::pin_project! {
214 | |     /// Future that pairs with [`UploadThroughput`] to add a minimum throughput
215 | |     /// requirement to a request upload stream.
216 | |     struct UploadThroughputCheckFuture {
...   |
231 | |     }
232 | | }
    | |_- `UploadThroughputCheckFuture` declared as private
...
333 | / pin_project_lite::pin_project! {
334 | |     #[project = EnumProj]
335 | |     pub(crate) enum MaybeUploadThroughputCheckFuture {
336 | |         Direct { #[pin] future: HttpConnectorFuture },
337 | |         Checked { #[pin] future: UploadThroughputCheckFuture },
338 | |     }
339 | | }
    | |_^ can't leak private type
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::__pin_project_reconstruct` which comes from the expansion of the macro `pin_project_lite::pin_project` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0446]: private type `UploadThroughputCheckFuture` in public interface
   --> /Users/amanr/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/aws-smithy-runtime-1.3.1/src/client/http/body/minimum_throughput.rs:333:1
    |
213 | / pin_project_lite::pin_project! {
214 | |     /// Future that pairs with [`UploadThroughput`] to add a minimum throughput
215 | |     /// requirement to a request upload stream.
216 | |     struct UploadThroughputCheckFuture {
...   |
231 | |     }
232 | | }
    | |_- `UploadThroughputCheckFuture` declared as private
...
333 | / pin_project_lite::pin_project! {
334 | |     #[project = EnumProj]
335 | |     pub(crate) enum MaybeUploadThroughputCheckFuture {
336 | |         Direct { #[pin] future: HttpConnectorFuture },
337 | |         Checked { #[pin] future: UploadThroughputCheckFuture },
338 | |     }
339 | | }
    | |_^ can't leak private type
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::__pin_project_make_proj_ty` which comes from the expansion of the macro `pin_project_lite::pin_project` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0446`.
error: could not compile `aws-smithy-runtime` (lib) due to 2 previous errors

Even after removing aws-sdk-apigatewaymanagement from my Cargo.toml, This error still persists. I also tested this by creating a new project using cargo new and adding only the aws-sdk-apigatewaymanagement crate. The same error occurs on building.
How do I fix this issue?

Just updating rust using rustup solved the issue
